# If I disable the app store with screen time will my apps still automatically update if set to do so?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, screen-time

I can't think of a quick way to test it out.

Comment: You can't think of a quick way to test this other than actually doing it and seeing if the apps update?

Comment: But then how would I know if the app actually has updated itself? It doesn't tell you. Also I only have a few apps, so it could take a week or so for an update to be released.

Comment: Disable the store, wait a few weeks, enable it again. Then check whether any app has an update pending since days//weeks.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately apps will stop updating until you allow access to the App Store again. So you will need to periodically enable the App Store to install (security) updates.